# QT Creator CMake Configuration Issue: Adding parameters ignored

Tags: linux, cmake, qt-creator

In QT Creator it is possible to load a project from a CMakeLists.txt.

Executing cmake sometimes needs defines or other parameters to be configured correctly. In my case, this is done by executing on the command line

`cmake .. -DTARGET_MYPROJECT_NAME=MY_App -DTARGET_MYPROJECT_OS=linux`

To set the values for `TARGET_MYPROJECT_NAME` and `TARGET_MYPROJECT_OS` in QT Creator, one needs to go to Projects (Ctrl+5) and enter the keys and values for each corresponding build type (release and debug etc.).

When I finished entering the parameters in the input box, I hit "Apply Configuration Changes" right below the input box.

When clicking "Build" -> "Run Cmake" it fails, because the parameters are not given. On the Command Line output from within QT-Creator, I can see they are not set. If I repeat the procedure but do not hit "Apply Configuration Changes", it asks me to save before running cmake. Outcome is the same.

What am I missing? Why is it not calling CMake with the given parameters. Cleared CMakeFiles folder and deleted CMakeLists.txt.user and CMakeCache.txt but no change so far.

I am using QT Creator 4.13.1 (The Snap) and Ubuntu 20.04
Update: Giving the parameters in "Initial CMake parameters" instead of the list, results in the CmakeCache.txt not containing those parameters, and the CMakeLists.txt.user file in containing those parameters. Also this step is reproducable (installed other cmake and qt creator with apt get instead of the snap store)

Edit: Done the change from generator expression conflicts with names

Answer (score 1):

1. [`TARGET_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html?highlight=target_name#output-related-expressions) is the built-in generator expression. Just rename it to `MY_TARGET_NAME`, for instance.
2. Qt Creator prior to v4.13 has [some issues](https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-creator-4.13-released)

> We completely revamped the CMake support in Qt Creator. One of the biggest issues with CMake support was that Qt Creator had its own idea about the build configuration of a project, and that could conflict heavily with an existing build, or could cause problems if the configuration was changed on the command line later. In the new version, Qt Creator accepts an existing build configuration as the truth, no matter what for example the settings for CMake in the kit are.

3. When you add a custom definition, it appears on the command line first, then it is saved to CMakeCache.txt, and is read from this file further.

Update.

[CMP0037](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0037.html):

> Target names reserved by one or more CMake generators are not allowed. Among others these include all, clean, help, and install.

Comment: Thank you. I am using QT Creator 4.13 (updated the question). Am I right that my main problem seems to be, that my parameter names are exactly like built in generator expressions? It is a rather big effort for me to change the parameter names, is there a way around?

Comment: Try to set the old behavior [`cmake_policy(SET CMP0037 OLD)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0037.html) at the top of CMakeLists.txt (just after `cmake_minimum_required`).

Comment: I changed internal variable names, from my understanding I therefore do not need the old behavior. It still is not working. The parameters are not set.